# Java Whileloop ends, but the boolean is still true

Tags: java, while-loop, blocking

My problem is, my while loop ends, is blocking my code but the condition is still true

```
while (trees.size() > 0) {
            Vector2 tree = trees.get(0);
            if (tileMap[(int) tree.x][(int) tree.y].canPlanetsGrowOn() && r.nextInt(20) == 3) {
                
                int gX = Math.round(tree.x);
                int gY = Math.round(tree.y);
                                
                TreeEntity tr = new TreeEntity(game, gX*32, gY*32);
                entityManager.addEntity(tr);
            }
            trees.remove(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Finished work");
```

[There's no "Finished work", but it also didn't print out any other info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wzcd.png)

My trees is a Vector2 List. Vector2 contains a x and y. I hope someone can help.

Comment: What condition is still true? How can your while loop end but still block the execution of the rest of your code? Your question is very unclear and I honestly don't understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I'm giving a sysout after the while loop should end, but it ends and no sysout. I'm also editing the code, because I forgot the sysout

Comment: Since you can't see the "Finished work" printed then most likely your while loop does NOT end. Your intuition that something blocks could be true. The first suspect in your code would probably be this line of code `entityManager.addEntity(tr)`. One way to figure out would be run this in debug mode in Intellij and interrupt the thread, to see on which statement does it sit. Alternatively just add print before and after around that statement, run the thing and see if your last thing printed is "before" which would indicate that the code never reaches "after"

Comment: @artur I have tried now and saw that it's working if I remove the `  entityManager.addEntity(tr);` But in there, is just ```public void addEntity(Entity e) {
  entities.add(e);
  if (e instanceof StaticEntity) {
   plants[(int) (e.getX() / 32)][(int) (e.getY() / 32)] = (StaticEntity) e;
   System.out.println(e.getX() /32 + ", " +  e.getY() / 32 + "\n" + plants[(int) (e.getX() / 32)][(int) (e.getY() / 32)]);
  }
 }``` and I didn't find the error that's blocking. After a time it just didn't work. And I also don't know how to enable debug mode in eclipse

Comment: what is the `entities` object and how it gets instantiated?

Comment: debug in eclipse: 'Run - Debug', or Right-Click in Main class and 'Debug as'; or the debug button left of run on toolbar, or just press F11 (but before starting, set breakpoints (double-click left off line number or Ctrl-Shift-B)